# Show html based on property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using Angular in my project.
I want to hide a piece of code to based on a property:

```
  {{ user.Active ? </div></div> : ''  }}
```

That piece of code is not making the two closing div's rendered into the html. Angular is not able to parse it.

Can you let me know how should modify that line to render my two closing divs.

EDIT:

I just want to render two closing divs. I don't want to render div tags with ng-if attributes as mentioned in the replies in this thread.

Comment: have you tried ng-hide - ng-show?

Comment: @Tushar that won't work inside `{{}}`, he will need `ng-bind-html` there

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
<div ng-show='user.active'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to do what you are trying to do. What you are trying to do will allow non-escaped text to be placed into the dom. Non-escaped text can allow for XSS vulnerabilities. You should do the following.

```
<div ng-if="user.Active === true"></div>
```

This will only put the div in the dom if the 'user.Active' is true. This is the better way to do what you are trying to do. Of course, there is probably an even better way to do it with just CSS, but you would have to add more details to give that answer.

Comment: The different between ng-show and ng-if is that ng-show will have the item in the DOM, even if the expression is false. It will just hide it with a 'display:none" style. Whereas ng-if will completely remove it from the DOM if the expression is false. So, that is the difference between the two. You can decide which is best for what you are trying to do.